# Google Analytics e cookies

Tags: cookies, google-analytics-api

A minha duvida é: estou a desenvolver um website e pretendo monitorizar os analytics com o Google Analytics, no entanto andei a ler uns artigos sobre cookies e não percebi se preciso de programar o meu website com algum tipo de cookies para poder no futuro utilizar a ferramenta a google, ou se pura e simplesmente não preciso de fazer nada no meu website.

Comment: Já coloquei o Google Analytics num site que fiz e não precisei fazer nada disso, apenas o código `JavaScript`. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=pt-br